# How do I control adding the same movieclip different places in AS3?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, movieclip

Time for a really nooby question, but I can't find a satisfying answer.. Everytime I search for array tutorials, they are about how you put different strings of text into an array and accessing them again.

**Here is what I have:**

When you start the game, you are able to press lets just say 5 buttons. When you press button 1 flash (simplified) goes:

addChild(backGround)
addChild(world)
world.gotoAndStop(1) 
addChild(character)

And so on with the other buttons, changing which world you're in.

**Here is what I want:**
I want to be able to add *the same* enemy movieclip specific places, according to which button the player presses.

So let's say the player presses button 3, and in world 3 I want there to be an enemy at x 200, y 300, and an enemy at x 600, y 450 and one more enemy some other specific place. All enemies are the same movieclip.

So how can add enemies like that???

I know I need an array, but how do i access the movieclip like I want to?

My code:

package  {

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class Main extends MovieClip {

    public var character:Character;
    public var backGround:BackGround;
    public var world:World;
    public var worldMap:WorldMap;
    public var monster1:Monster1;
    public var worldLevel:int;
    public var currentLevel:int;

    public function Main() {

        backGround = new BackGround;
        world = new World;
        monster1 = new Monster1
        character = new Character();
        worldMap = new WorldMap;

        // Every world lies in a different frame in the "world" movieclip 
        world.worldDangers.gotoAndStop(currentLevel);
        world.SafeGround.gotoAndStop(currentLevel);
        world.GroundViz.gotoAndStop(currentLevel);
        world.PortaltoNew.gotoAndStop(currentLevel);

        //----- on the world map is the different world buttons ---
        addChild(worldMap);

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveWorld)

        //------------------- world buttons --------------------
        worldMap.buttonWorld1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoWorld1)
        worldMap.buttonWorld2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoWorld2)
        worldMap.buttonWorld3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoWorld3)
        worldMap.buttonWorld4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoWorld4)
    }


    function gotoWorld1 (m:MouseEvent):void
    {
        currentLevel = 1;
        addChild(backGround);

        addChild(world);
        world.x = 0;
        world.y = 0;

        isinWorld = true

        addChild(character);
        character.x = 300;
        character.y = 650;
        character.gotoAndStop(3);


        worldMap.parent.removeChild(worldMap);
    }


    //----------------- function world 2 ---------------------
    function gotoWorld2 (m:MouseEvent):void
    {
        currentLevel = 2;
        addChild(backGround);

        addChild(world);
        world.x = 0;
        world.y = 0;

        isinWorld = true

        addChild(character);
        character.x = 300;
        character.y = 650;
        character.gotoAndStop(3);

        worldMap.parent.removeChild(worldMap);
    }

    //----------------- function world 3 -----------------------
    function gotoWorld3 (m:MouseEvent):void
    {
        currentLevel = 3;
        addChild(backGround);

        addChild(world);
        world.x = 0;
        world.y = 0;

        isinWorld = true

        addChild(character);
        character.x = 300;
        character.y = 650;
        character.gotoAndStop(3);


        worldMap.parent.removeChild(worldMap);
    }

    function gotoWorld4 (m:MouseEvent):void
    {
        currentLevel = 4;
        addChild(backGround);

        addChild(world);
        world.x = 0;
        world.y = 0;

        isinWorld = true

        addChild(character);
        character.x = 300;
        character.y = 650;
        character.gotoAndStop(3);


        worldMap.parent.removeChild(worldMap);
    }




    function moveWorld (e:Event)
    {


        if (isinWorld)
        {
            world.y = world.y + 5;


            if (character.hitTestObject(monster1))
            {
            world.parent.removeChild(world);
            backGround.parent.removeChild(backGround);
            character.parent.removeChild(character);

            isinWorld = false


            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: In the array you will just save enemies coordinates not objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following should do the trick:

```
// Define a bunch of positions for this world
var positions:Array = [
    new Point(200, 300),
    new Point(600, 450),
    new Point(50, 350)
];

// Probably makes sense to store your enemies on 
// an array for access later in your game
var enemies:Array = [];

// Temporary variables for the loop
var enemy:Enemy;
var position:Point;

// Iterate over the positions array
for (var i:int = 0; i < positions.length; i ++) 
{
    // Get the position
    position = positions[i] as Point;

    // Create a new enemy and position him
    enemy = new Enemy();
    enemy.x = position.x;
    enemy.y = position.y;

    // Add child and store it on an array 
    addChild(enemy);
    enemies.push(enemy);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Would I for example write this code in the button3 (the button that takes you to world 3) function? And then write the same code in the button4 function, with different positions? (since the enemies will have different positions in world 4)